# HTML Form Output Formatting (with JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I want to make an HTML form that churns out formatted email signatures.

- I want the output on 
  1) separate lines and 
  2) have each line of be formatted uniquely. So, first line bold and blue, second like non-bold and grey font, etc. like typical email signatures. So far it all appears in one long identically formatted output.
- Eventually I'd like blank entries to be omitted and to add an automatic copy function, but I can tackle those later.

Spent a few dozen hours on this and can't get it, so hoping for some guidance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang = "en-US">
    <title>Email Signature</title>
    <head>
    <body>
    <font face="century gothic">
    <h3>Creating Signature</h3>
    <p>Enter you information<p>      
    <form>
    Name<br>
    <input type="text" name="wholename" ><br>
    <br>Position</br>
    <input type="text" name="pos"><br>
    <br>Position 2</br>
    <input type="text" name="pospos"><br>
    <br>Phone 1</br>
    <input type="text" name="phone"><br>
    <br>Phone 2</br>
    <input type="text" name="phonephone"><br>     
    <p>Select Location<p>    
     <input type="radio" name="location" value="Redding" checked>Redding<br>
     <input type="radio" name="location" value="San Francisco" checked> San Francisco<br>
     <input type="radio" name="location" value="Woodland Hills" checked> Los Angeles<br><br>   
    <input type="checkbox" name="billingtoo" onclick="FillBilling(this.form)">
    <em>Check this box when you're all set</em>
    <p>   
    <b>Your Custom Signature:</b><br><br>
    <textarea type="textarea" id="billingname" style="font-family:century gothic;font-size:1.2em;color:rgb(126,128,130)" rows="10" cols="40" ></textarea><br> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function copyText(){
     document.getElementById("billingname").select();
     document.execCommand('copy');
    }
    function FillBilling(f) {
    f.billingname.value = 
      f.wholename.value  + " " + f.pos.value + " | " + f.pospos.value + "" + f.phone.value + "  " + f.phonephone.value + "  " + f.location.value;}
      if(f.billingtoo.checked == true) {}
    </script> 
    </form>
    <br><br><br><br>
    </font face>
    </head>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you want to use a `<textarea>` because that doesn't allow for multiple formatting like you want in the signature.  Try using a `<div>` with separate `<p>` tags, like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang = "en-US">
    <title>Email Signature</title>
    <head>
    <body>
    <font face="century gothic">
    <h3>Creating Signature</h3>
    <p>Enter you information<p>      
    <form>
    Name<br>
    <input type="text" name="wholename" value="John Doe"><br>
    <br>Position</br>
    <input type="text" name="pos" value="Systems Engineer"><br>
    <br>Position 2</br>
    <input type="text" name="pospos" value="Senior Manager"><br>
    <br>Phone 1</br>
    <input type="text" name="phone" value="(123)-456-7890"><br>
    <br>Phone 2</br>
    <input type="text" name="phonephone" value="(123)-456-7890"><br>     
    <p>Select Location<p>    
     <input type="radio" name="location" value="Redding" checked>Redding<br>
     <input type="radio" name="location" value="San Francisco" checked> San Francisco<br>
     <input type="radio" name="location" value="Woodland Hills" checked> Los Angeles<br><br>   
    <input type="checkbox" name="billingtoo" onclick="FillBilling(this.form)">
    <em>Check this box when you're all set</em>
    <p>   
    <b>Your Custom Signature:</b><br><br>
    <div id="billingname" style="width: 400px; height: 300px; border: solid black 2px;">
     <b id="wholename" style="margin:0; line-height:14px; display:inline-block; color:#245996"></b>
        <p id="pos" style="margin:0; line-height:14px; display:inline-block; color:#245996"></p>
        <p id="pospos" style="margin:0; line-height:14px; display:inline-block; color:#245996"></p>
        <p id="phone" style="margin:0; line-height:14px; color:grey"></p>
        <p id="phonephone" style="margin:0; line-height:14px; color:grey"></p>
        <p id="location" style="margin:0; line-height:14px; color:grey"></p>
    
    </div>
    <br> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function copyText(){
     document.getElementById("billingname").select();
     document.execCommand('copy');
    }
    function FillBilling(f) {
      document.getElementById("wholename").innerHTML = f.wholename.value + " ";
      document.getElementById("pos").innerHTML = f.pos.value + " | ";
      document.getElementById("pospos").innerHTML = f.pospos.value;
      document.getElementById("phone").innerHTML = f.phone.value;
      document.getElementById("phonephone").innerHTML = f.phonephone.value;
      document.getElementById("location").innerHTML = f.location.value;
      }
      //if(f.billingtoo.checked == true) {}
    </script> 
    </form>
    <br><br><br><br>
    </font face>
    </head>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Let me know if you have any questions about the code or if I misinterpreted what you wanted.

***Happy Coding!***

Comment: Agillgilla!! Thanks SO much this has been plaguing me and your code works great. You the best.